# Conflict between the Braintree iOS SDK & Card I/O iOS SDK: duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, paypal, braintree, card.io

In the App I am developing (with Xcode 6.1, for iOS 7&8), I am using [Card IO](https://www.card.io/) to capture the credit card information and use [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) as the payment method. Problems happens when I include [Card IO iOS SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK), together with [Braintree iOS SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/sdk/client) which was imported by Cocoapods, I got the error:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOCreditCardInfo in:
>       /MyApp/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOPaymentViewController in:
>       /MyApp/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOView in:
>       /MyApp/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CardIOCreditCardInfo in:
>       /MyApp/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CardIOPaymentViewController in:
>       /MyApp/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CardIOView in:
>       /MyApp/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>       /MyApp/CardIO/libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-armv7-master.o)
>   ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Turns out that Braintree includes Paypay SDK, which already contains the library of CardIO.

I have tried 
1)to delete(remove reference) libCardIO.a in CardIO folder, the APP is able to be built and run, but the view controller and the camera of CardIO cannot be open properly.
2)to delete(remove reference) the Paypal folder from Braintree, got the error below.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTPayPalButton", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libPods-Vinyo-2-Braintree.a(Braintree.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTPayPalViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libPods-Vinyo-2-Braintree.a(BTPaymentProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTPayPalAppSwitchHandler", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libPods-Vinyo-2-Braintree.a(BTPaymentProvider.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libPods-Vinyo-2-Braintree.a(Braintree.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Looking for a feasible and secure way to integrate these two SDK properly and make it work. Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

Your first approach is the correct one. From the information you've provided so far, I'm not sure why it didn't work for you.

Please see https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/53#issuecomment-58379403 for some specific advice.

(In another week or two this should get easier, as the correct card.io headers will be included with the Braintree iOS SDK.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and the link you provided. I tried remove the libCardIO.a and add all the headers. But the CardIOPaymentViewController still cannot be initialised properly. Even got the error in viewWillApprear:"+[CardIOPaymentViewController preload]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x365ffc." Before adding Braintree SDK, CardIO was working well.

Comment: @willyang the `preload` method was added to card.io in Version 3.9.0. Since you have reverted your card.io headers to the 3.8.2 version used by the Braintree SDK, that method is not defined. -> I think that your simplest solution will be to wait a few days until the next update of the Braintree SDK, which should solve the problem once and for all.

Comment: That's great! Looking forward to the new SDK. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Already updated to the latest braintree sdk, after a few configurations for Xcode, everything works like a charm. Thanks!